# Can't start the OS because of video problems

Tags: system-installation, display, startup

I have a Windows 10 computer, I've created a 100 GB partition to install Elementary OS, I've used Rufus to create a bootable USB device. The installing process is perfect, I have no problem, it runs with full resolution. But then, when it's finished and I try to start the system I get this:

[image]

I've had the same problem with Ubuntu, but that time I didn't really want to fix it, so I've simply uninstalled it. But this time I want the system running. Can you help me?

I've discovered that if I use GRUB to start elementary's recovery mode, and I continue normal boot from that, I haven't this problem but the screen resolution is fixed to 480x260 (4:3) and I can't change it.

Thank you for your time, hope you have a solution to my problem.

Comment: We need your graphics card model to help you. But basically what you have to do is booting in recovery mode, install your graphics driver and then reboot.

Comment: @Maccer the problem was that Ubuntu (and Ubuntu like OS, such as Elementary OS) doesn't recognize my AMD graphics card in dual boot. After installing drivers in recovery mode, the system didn't start.

Comment: Did or didn't start?